# Why does dataframe column contain numbers having percent-sign appended?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, indexing, concatenation

When I incorrectly concatenated two dataframes with differing indexes, the second dataframe's columns had their dtype changed from 'int8' to 'float64' and the numbers had a percent sign appended. I understand the change in dtype but I haven't found documentation about the appended percent sign. Is appending a percent sign new behavior? Where is this documented? When did the behavior change occur? Some googling didn't find the answers so I'm  hereby making this behavior more discoverable for others.

```
# incorrect concat
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1],index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([2],index=[1])
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis='columns') # needs join='inner' or df2.reset_index()

# corrected concat
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1],index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([2],index=[1])
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis='columns',join='inner')
```

Comment: Are you working in jupyter and/or did you change some display options so that floats are always displayed as percentages? Otherwise that is _not_ a behavior that happens. (i.e. do you modify `pd.options.display.float_format`?)

Comment: Ah. Yes, I'm working in jupyter. Yes again, I had a bug where I left in an extraneous percent-sign. `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}%'.format`. I see that my entire notebook is now `int8` so I didn't realize that *all* floats would have same issue.

Comment: Your comment is the accepted answer.